# Supersede default route to other network interfaces

Tags: networking, dhcp, gateway

I have two network interfaces: `wlan0` and `eth1`.

- `wlan0` connects to a camera over WiFi, getting all it's info from the camera's DHCP (the camera itself hosts its own network).
- `eth1` connects to the internet (via a router), also getting it's info from DHCP.

Sometimes `wlan0` disconnects, and reconnects, causing it to be set as the default gateway, killing my internet connection.

It would, however, be awesome if I could connect to the internet over `wlan0` if `eth1` wasn't present (this would be a completely separate connection to the camera - and instead of the camera).

How do I make sure that `eth1` is the preferred route to the internet while still enabling `wlan0` to be allocated an IP address via DHCP (for the camera connection), and still enabling `wlan0` to access the internet (in the case that `eth1` isn't connected) with a single configuration?

My current attempt is to add:

```
interface "wlan0"
 {
  supercede routers "";
 }
```

to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`. This throws errors, but somehow seems to have the desired effect.

Prior to this, I wrote a custom rule in `/etc/dhcp/dhcp-enter-hooks.d` to `unset new_routers` if `eth1` wasn't the interface connecting.

FWIW, this box is purely command line, and I'm not using the graphical network manager.

Comment: I don't understand, please explain in more detail or make a drawing... both eth1 and wlan0 connect to the same router but wlan0 doesn't have Internet access? That should be working out of the box.  Furthermore, the IP camera also connects to the same router?

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I suppose the router has no wireless functionalities, that the camera is hosting a DHCP server and that what you really want it to have a stable Internet connection even when the camera does something stupid. ;-) Are all my assumptions correct?  (If not and this is more complicated, please explain what you're trying to accomplish by taking a step back... thinking about what you want... and *only then* write a one-sentence problem description without detail. E.g.: I'm trying to watch my dog from work.  I'm trying to secure my house. ...)

Comment: Exactly. I'm trying to connect a box to the internet (#1 priority) most often using `eth1`, but sometimes internet through `wlan0`. Most of the time there is a camera connected on `wlan0` (which hosts DHCP server to allocate IP to the box), but sometimes the box needs to connect to the internet over `wlan0`, and I want to make sure the box is connected to the internet.

Comment: In [this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=150083#c1) there are a lot of answers to this issue, namely: Specifying $GATEWAYDEV in /etc/sysconfig/network; specifying $GATEWAY in ifcfg-ethX; specifying 'supersede routers AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD;' in /etc/dhclient.conf

Answer (score 0):

For your use case (let's take the example of "The laptop is connected most of the time to the camera to watch my dog remotely on `wlan0` and connected to the Internet on `eth0`, but every now and then I'd like to take my laptop into the library to use Google using `ẁlan0` as the dog will follow me there anyway and I can watch it in RL") I see two options that will be easier then what you're trying to do:

1. Disallow automatic connection to the Internet on `wlan0`.

   This will automatically reconnect `wlan0` to the camera after a power failure, a hiccup in the connection to the camera, ...

   If you want to move to the library, execute a script that: `ifdown eth0&&iwconfig wlan0 essid WiFi-Internet` and when returning `ifup eth0&&iwconfig wlan0 essid WiFi-Camera`
2. Add another wireless card, bond that with the Ethernet card and forget about everything.

**Why?** Computers don't like "sometimes": they like "always":  #1 is "sometimes" without expense and as you're handling the machine anyway, having a script `library.sh` and `monitoring.sh` makes sense (as you're on command-line anyway).  #2 is more expensive, but is the most robust solution of all.

So, *not an answer to your question*, but 2 *solutions to your problem!*  **;-)**